# Running a python program in Windows?

Tags: python, cmd, interpreter

I have Python 3.6 and Windows 7.

I am able to successfully start the python interpreter in interactive mode, which I have confirmed by going to cmd, and typing in python, so my computer knows how to find the interpreter.

I am confused however, as to how to access files from the interpreter. For example, I have a file called test.py (yes, I made sure the correct file extension was used).

However, I do not know how to access test.py from the interpreter. Let us say for the sake of argument that the test.py file has been stored in C:\ How then would I access test.py from the interpreter?

Comment: Why put it at the root of the drive? If you put it in a directory on Python's path, you can just `import test`.

Comment: How would I put it in a directory on Python's path?

Comment: Then say that. Say what you've found out, [edit] the question to explain what you've tried and what precisely the remaining problem is. Do you not know how to create a directory? How to determine what's already on the path? How to add *to* the path? **Be specific.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The simplest way would be to  just do the following in cmd:

   `C:\path\to\file\test.py`

   Windows recognizes the file extension and runs it with Python.
2. Or you can change the directory to where the Python program/script is by using the cd command in the command prompt:

   `cd C:\path\to\file`

   Start Python in the terminal and import the script using the import function:

   `import test`

   You do not have to specify the .py file extension. The script will only run once per process so you'll need to use the reload function to run it after it's first import.
3. You can make python run the script from a specific directory:

   `python C:\path\to\file\test.py`

Comment: Hi, Fluxenein, can i have a follow up clarification please? You stated with #2 that:

" you can change the directory to where the Python program/script is by using the cd command in the command prompt"

Would I need to change the directory everytime I ran a different program/script or, would I be able to change the directory permanently?

Comment: You'll have to change it every time. Or you can hold SHIFT+Right click and choose open command window here.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I thought that might be the case but wanted to clarify

Comment: What's happening now is that you are using Command Prompt to pass an input to Python interpreter. You can either "tell" it the full path(python C:\path\to\file\text.py)  or change to the folder the file is in and make python run the file. When you change the path, cms still passes on the full path, you just don't have to type it out.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt you need to navigate to the file location. In your case it is in C:\ drive, so type:

> cd C:\

and then proceed to run your program:

> python test.py

or you could do it in one line:

> python C:\test.py

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are seeking, but I think what you are asking for is a IDE-like environment where you can load Python scripts, edit, and debug.

You already have IDLE, https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/idle.html, which came with the Python installation.

There are many IDEs available for Python. https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments Personally, I like using PyDev on Eclipse.

Comment: Must have poorly explained myself, I'm so sorry.

Comment: Are you saying that I misunderstood? If so, what are you seeking? Is one of the other answers here correct?

Comment: No, I am saying that is my fault 100%, I didnt really clarify what I needed to anyone. Was a criticism of me, not you :)

Comment: Since no answer has been chosen, it seems that none of the answers are meeting your question. Perhaps you should say something more in the question about what you are seeking so that someone might answer it.

Comment: Chosen, yet. :)